# Slice NSArray from end of array

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsarray, reverse, slice

What is the best way to "slice" an `NSArray` from the end, rather than the beginning, of the array (for example, finding the subarray containing the last few elements of a `NSArray` of unknown length)? In Python, you can use negative indices to accomplish this, e.g.:

```
new_list = old_list[-5:-3]
```

What's the most natural way to do this in Objective-C?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's nothing to match Python's nice syntax for this, but you could do:

```
NSUInteger count = [myArray count];
NSArray * slice = [myArray subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){count-n, n}];
```

You could also write up a category for `NSArray`, something like:

```
@interface NSArray (jrdioko_slice)
- (NSArray *) jrdioko_sliceFrom:(NSInteger)start to:(NSInteger)stop;
@end
```

If you want to go this route, the Python source will certainly repay study. A [list object](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/tags/r265/Objects/listobject.c?content-type=text%2Fplain) creates a [slice object](http://svn.python.org/view/%2acheckout%2a/python/tags/r265/Objects/sliceobject.c?content-type=text%2Fplain) when a slice operation is performed. The relevant method on a slice object is `PySlice_GetIndicesEx`. You'll just have to be careful turning those indexes into an `NSRange`. As the comment in that function warns "this is harder to get right than you might think". (I'll try to take a crack at this later.)

UPDATE: Here we have a slice category on `NSArray`. The index calculation logic is pretty much straight out of the Python code that I linked to above.* It's actually a lot easier than I thought at first if you don't have to worry about the stride part of a Python slice. I've run this through a few tests and it seems to work the same as the Python version.

```
@interface NSArray (WSS_Slice)
- (NSArray *)WSS_arrayBySlicingFrom:(NSInteger)start to:(NSInteger)stop;
@end

// Python allows skipping any of the indexes of a slice and supplies default
// values. Skipping an argument to a method is not possible, so (ab)use 
// NSNotFound as "not specified" index value. The other way to do this would
// be with varargs, which might be even handier if one decided to implement
// the stride functionality.
enum {
    WSS_SliceNoIndex = NSNotFound
};

@implementation NSArray (WSS_Slice)

- (NSArray *)WSS_arrayBySlicingFrom:(NSInteger)start to:(NSInteger)stop {
    // There's an important caveat here: specifying the parameters as 
    // NSInteger allows negative indexes, but limits the method's 
    // (theoretical) use: the maximum size of an NSArray is NSUIntegerMax, 
    // which is quite a bit larger than NSIntegerMax. 
    NSUInteger count = [self count];

    // Due to this caveat, bail if the array is too big.
    if( count >= NSIntegerMax ) return nil;

    // Define default start and stop
    NSInteger defaultStart = 0;
    NSInteger defaultStop = count;

    // Set start to default if not specified
    if( start == WSS_SliceNoIndex ){
        start = defaultStart;
    }
    else {
        // If start is negative, change it to the correct positive index.
        if( start < 0 ) start += count;
        // Correct for out-of-bounds index:
        // If it's _still_ negative, set it to 0
        if( start < 0 ) start = 0;
        // If it's past the end, set it to just include the last item
        if( start > count ) start = count;
    }

    // Perform all the same calculations on stop
    if( stop == WSS_SliceNoIndex ){
        stop = defaultStop;
    }
    else {
        if( stop < 0 ) stop += count;
        if( stop < 0 ) stop = 0;
        if( stop > count ) stop = count;
    }

    // Calculate slice length with corrected indexes
    NSInteger sliceLength = stop - start;

    // If no slice, return a new empty array
    if( sliceLength <= 0 ){
        return [NSArray array];
    }
    else {
        return [self subarrayWithRange:(NSRange){start, sliceLength}];
    }

}
@end
```

<sub>*Therefore I think I need to include a link to the [Python License](http://docs.python.org/release/2.6.5/license) and also note that this **may** still be “Copyright © 2001-2010 Python Software Foundation; All Rights Reserved”, because although this looks to me like a separately-copyrightable derivative work, I ain't a lawyer.</sub>

Comment: +1 for mentioning categories , also for  jrdioko_sliceFrom :)

Comment: In your initial answer, why is it `count-n-1` instead of `count-n`?

Comment: @jrdioko: Oh, that's embarassing. Trying to avoid the off-by-one error and walking right into it. You're correct to point that out; should be just count-n.

Comment: Well it looked right to me too until I started thinking about it. Thanks for the edit.