# What's Objective c NSArray's elements most elegant syntax (equivalent to Python's)?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

Let's say I have an NSArray with 5 elements:

```
myArr = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

What's the most elegant way to fetch some of its items? Something similar to Python's:

```
myArr[1 : -1] //will return [1,2,3]
```

Thanks, Nili

Comment: See also: [Slice NSArray from end of array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6337339)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSArray *subsetArray = [originalArray objectsAtIndexes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)]];
```

You can change the starting point and length inside of the `NSMakeRange()`.

Comment: Don't you want `NSMakeRange(1, 3)`?

Comment: Yeah, I was just writing 0,2 as a random example. I'll edit to match the op's example. thanks @trojanfoe

Answer (score 1):

The closest built-in solution is subarrayWithRange:

```
NSArray *subarray = [array subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 3)];
```